# How to set cached for css and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, caching

So I have desperately been looking for a way to set my website cached expiration. I would like to set the css and js expiration but I couldn't find any useful information. I tried to use

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

but it just doesn't work. Most of the material online just talk about Apache, xml and others but I don't use them. Is there a way to implement the expiration using php or html? and how is it done?

Comment: Did you take a look to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141643/how-do-i-set-expiration-on-css-js-and-images) ?

Comment: @dtlvd yes but it's not html nor php. It says htaccess and I did try but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using Apache to host your web app ?

Comment: Try as hard as you like, at the end of the day it is up to the users browser to choose what to cache. However, you can always pass a `header()` in PHP which is the same as what Apache does.

Comment: I do agree @Tigger but by default you can configure that with Apache and if the browser doesn't "override" that the Apache configuration should be effective.

Comment: @Tigger I am using Filezilla to host it and so how do I pass a header in php to set the cache expiration?

Comment: @DanielOMensah there are many ways you can do this, I'll post a quick example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different ways to do this. The following is a simple example only.

CSS file called `test.css` (do the same for the Javascript).

```
body { background:#abc }
```

A PHP file to render the requested CSS or Javascript called `t.php` that includes the no cache request headers:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// use a switch statement for basic checking and flexibility  
switch($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) {
    case '/css':
        echo file_get_contents('./test.css');
        exit;
    case '/js':
        echo file_get_contents('./test.js');
        exit;
}
?>
```

And the header section of the HTML/PHP file

```
<head>                              
<link rel="stylesheet" href="t.php/css" />
<script src="t.php/js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Great, best one so far. But I am having a problem with the css. It doesn't link the css. It works fine with the javascript.

Comment: @DanielOMensah It is most likely a file path issue. You can test by visiting the URI directly. If you let me know the path and file name of the CSS and HTML / PHP files, I'll update the answer.